# Get notified when PlayStore adds app icon to home screen

Tags: android

Does PlayStore send any broadcast message with "com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" action, when it adds app shortcut to home screen before/after the app get installed?

I heard of the following method:

1. Add `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />` to `manifest.xml`
2. Extend `BroadcastReceiver` class, then override `onReceive()` method

Is it true that the above 2 steps will let app get notified when Play Store add app shortcut to home screen?

Answer (score 0):

Here I don't think there is any listener available to listen shortcuts directly. but you could go through some tricky way like :

1) Listen to application install using listener. you could achieve it by registering following way :

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
     <data android:scheme="package"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

2) In your AppListener broadcast receiver whenever you will get it triggered, keep delay of 5 to 10 second and perform action to get all installed applications using :

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

- Now you have all installed packages, iterate through them and `callgetLaunchIntentForPackage()` on each item
- If a valid intent is returned, that means it exists on launcher, else if it returns null, the package doesn't launch from home screen.

REASON : Home screens shortcuts are subset of the launcher apps :)